# Output values of xml file in a text file with format

Tags: c#, xml, console-application

How can I make a C# console program reads the attributes of an xml file then output it to a text file in the format: `textbox.Settings.Keywords.Add("attribute")` where attribute is the attribute. A sample of the xml file:

```
<Keywords>
...
<Keyword name = "if" />
<Keyword name = "else" />
...
</Keywords>
```

Comment: Please be more specific what you want for output. Your previous question has already been answered, showing how to get the attributes (so, please, nobody answer that part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
File.WriteAllLines( 
    XElement.Load(filename)
            .Descendants("Keyword")
            .Attributes("name")
            .Select(n => "textbox.Settings.Keywords.Add(\"" + n.Value + "\");")
            .ToArray()
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("...");

using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("yourfile.txt"))
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Element/@*"))
{
    writer.WriteLine(
        String.Format("textbox.Settings.Keywords.Add(\"{0}\")",
            node.Name));
}
```